# MySQL import without ID

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Im trying to import data from one database to another, but I want the import to just insert the values without corresponding ID's

So lets say I have 1000 rows.  I want my import to continue from 1001 upwards.
But my export starts at 1, and so it obviously just wants to replace the data, and I get an integrity constraint error.

How do I just do a simple insert with the data, and get new ID's instead of the import trying to replace old data with the exported ID's

Comment: Is the table where you are importing using autoincrement on the id?

Comment: Yes it does, just need to get it to ignore the ID on the import

Comment: then select only the columns which you want ignore the id and insert it.

Comment: Please show the code you are using to move the data between the two tables.

Comment: I figured that would be the answer, however I have 200 colums, is there any easy way to omit the ID, besides typing out all a SELECT statement with all 199 column names?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Its just a simple SELECT * (export to SQL), and then an SQL import.  Not much to see

Comment: yes - copy the source table in a new one. then remove the primary key an the autoincrement. update every id to NULL. then you can copy it like insert into dest_table select * from copy_table;

Answer (score 0):

Get all your original column names with

```
select * from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'orig table'
```

then

Asuming it as auto increment on the import table, i would do:

```
SELECT --allcolumns exept ID from the original table
INTO --new table
FROM  --original table
```

Comment: So the only way is to type all 199 columns out then eh?  damn...ok

Comment: make a select to get all the column names first, from information_schema.columns

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to copy the table to a new table (in to a new database if possible, so you can preserve the table name, but if your host doesn't give you access you can rename it on export). Use the Operations tab to copy the table.

Once you have the copy, you can drop the column you don't need anymore. Use the Drop link from the Structure tab.

Now you have the data exactly how you want it, so you can use the Export tab to dump to an .sql file. When creating the export, pick "data" only, not "structure and data":

[image: data dialog]

If you want, at this time you can use the "Rename exported databases/tables/columns" feature if you wish to rename the table. The import to your new database and you're all set. As long as (1) you don't have the auto_increment column present in the export and (2) your table name and rest of the structure match between the .sql file and the new table, the remaining values will be imported and the auto increment key will automatically increment as normal.

Answer (score 0):

You can just drop the id column from the source table.